# Set class attribute after inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
class ParentClassName(object):
    name = camel_case_to_underscore(cls.__name__)

class ChildClassName(Parent):
    pass

assert Parent().name == "parent_class_name" 
assert Child().name == "child_class_name" 
assert Child.name == "child_class_name" 
assert getattr(Child, 'name') == "child_class_name"
```

I would like to make a class, from which other classes can inherit and have got their name set basing on their class name.
Is it possible in python 3?

Comment: What's wrong with the already existing   `cls.__name__` attribute ?

Comment: cf my edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need it, it's already there:

```
>>> class Parent(): pass
... 
>>> class Child(): pass
... 
>>> Parent.__name__
'Parent'
>>> Child.__name__
'Child'
>>>
```

But if you really insist on rolling your own for whatever reason you didn't bother explaining, you can use a custom metaclass:

```
def camel_case_to_underscore(name):
    # your code here

class NamedType(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attribs):
        attribs["name"] = camel_case_to_underscore(name)
        return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attribs)

class Parent(metaclass=NamedType):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Comment: but what i want to do is to modify the name

Comment: What do you mean "modify the name" ?  I strongly suspect a XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here so you'd probably better explain what you're really trying to achieve with this (which problem you're trying to solve with this feature)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, classes are objects too, so you can set attributes, like you do in regular objects.

However, it's `Child.name`, not `Child().name`. `Child()` creates an instance, and assigns `name` to that, instead of the class.

Comment: but the thing is that I want to return value based on the class name

Comment: Just after you declare the class, put something like `ChildClassName.name = ChildClassName.__name__ + 'something else'`